# Manage browser DateTime, account DateTime and database DateTime

Tags: datetime

[image]

**Scenario**

- Bob and Jason are both staffs working for Hotel A in Malaysia.
- Bob accesses to Extranet from Malaysia.
- Jason accesses to Extranet from Dubai (assuming he is travelling).
- Both Bob and Jason expect the time showed in Extranet is the time    representing the current local time of the Hotel. In other words, for a guest going to checkout at 11am, both Bob and Jason see 11am on   Extranet (regardless of the timezone they are in).
- Bob is in the same time zone with the Hotel while Jason is not in    the same time zone with the hotel (4 hours behind).
- A is the value in the browser
- B is the value in text before being sent to server in JSON packet
- C is the value server received it
- D is the value the value being saved in Database

**Questions**

1. The value A on the browser if we do new Date:
2. On Bob browser: Sat Jan 26 2019 09:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)
3. On Jason browser: Sat Jan 26 2019 05:00:00 GMT+0400 (Dubai Time)
4. How do we create a value B that strip off the timezone before it’s
   being sent to the server?
5. We wanted to strip off the timezone because Jason (who are
   travelling in a different timezone) will intuitively understand
   all the date he inputs to the system meant to be the local time
   of the hotel instead of his current time. So, he don’t expect
   timezone conversion.
6. What is the datetime format we should send in JSON to ASP MVC
   server? The goal here is to get the Value instead of timezone.
7. What’s the value C? What is the datetime format we should save in Database? The goal here is to keep the Value instead of timezone.
8. Whats’s the value of D?

To help you answer my question, you may explain your idea using the format below

- Bob A: ?
- Bob B: ?
- Bob C: ?
- Bob D: ?
- Jason A: ?
- Jason B: ?
- Jason C: ?
- Jason D: ?

Answer (score 0):

- Bob A: TUE Jan 01 2019 11:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)
- Bob B: 2019-01-01T11:00:00
- Bob C: 2019-01-01T11:00:00 (UTC)
- Bob D: 2019-01-01T11:00:00
- Jason A: TUE Jan 01 2019 11:00:00 GMT+0400 (Dubai Time)
- Jason B: 2019-01-01T11:00:00
- Jason C: 2019-01-01T11:00:00 (UTC)
- Jason D: 2019-01-01T11:00:00